# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\\DBAL\\Platforms\\MySqlPlatform' not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a symfony 2 project. It was running just fine two different ubuntu systems. Now I have deployed it to an OpenShift instance and get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\\DBAL\\Platforms\\MySqlPlatform' not found in /var/lib/openshift/552ba6ecfcf93371e600007a/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php on line 80
```

I have no idea where to look for the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:
- remove folder "vendor"
- remove file composer.lock

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```

All good now

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file permissions. Is it executable? Does it exist at all?

Comment: put all the permissions to 777, but no change. And yes it does exist. Could it possibly be the autoloader that for some reason is confused about relative paths?

Comment: Yes, the next step is to verify paths in autoloader because if class exists and is executable Symfony2 just simply know nothing about it.

Comment: Any ideas on how to go about debugging the autoloader? and I have already tried putting everything to 777. Unfortunately with no success.

Comment: issue was that I didn't run php composer.phar install ;)

Comment: Ok, so you just copied the vendors?

Comment: yep. looking better now. Just need to resolve a configuration issue